# Preenchimento textbox para textbox

Tags: vba, textbox

Estou criando um projeto no VBA pois sou novo em programação e estou com dificuldades em uma parte do projeto.

Tenho 3 textbox, dois são usuario e senha, o outro vou carregar os usuarios separados por virgula ou por ponto e virgula, não importa qual.

Preciso que o meu projeto busque um usuario e senha por vez e que com a separação da virgula o do ponto e virgula, ele busque usuario pro campo de usuario e senha pro campo de senha.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Me desculpe se não soube explicar de forma melhor forma, mais meu projeto preenchera usario por usuario.
E do meu projeto vai preencher em uma pagina web. ele execultara uns comandos e irar passar pra outro login e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Não fez muito sentido... Você faria uma automação de login em um site específico? Textbox1: Usuario1 | TextBox2: Senha1 | TextBox3: Usuario2;Senha2;Usuario3;Senha3;...